# Problem with getFromLocationName in android

Tags: android, geocoding

I have a problem that drives me crazy and I need some support. 
I want to create an application that create an addresses list from a string that contains the location description, and I have the following code:

```
Geocoder fwdGeoGeocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.US);
String streetAdress = "160 Riverside Drive, New York, New York";
List<Address> locations = null;
try
{
    locations = fwdGeoGeocoder.getFromLocationName(streetAdress, 10);
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
myTopTextView.setText("Your current location is: Lat: "+locations.get(0).getLatitude()+
" Long: "+locations.get(0).getLongitude());
```

But locations is a void array after getFromLocationName is called and I don't know why. I tested this on my emulator that runs an android API lvl 7.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Hmm, works for me: 40.791192,-73.9790589  Have you tried to go through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Yes and location is still void. May be this because of AVD settings?

Comment: The target AVD has to support Google APIs and be able to access internet: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: Thanks iDroid, I forgot about Internet permission :)

Comment: @iDroid Can you please post an answer to this so I can accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target AVD has to support Google APIs and be able to access internet: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`